# How to convert action method to POST type in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have implemented Action to create customized method url.

```
getURL(){ "sampleURL"}

doBuildNow(){//Method implementation}

So Here URL : http://hostserver/job/jobName/sampleURL/buildNow
```

I would like to use this method as POST which doesn't work by default, I didn't find any clue from google search. Can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to force a Jenkins action method to only accept a post, add the '@RequirePOST' annotation to the method.

```
@RequirePOST
doBuildNow(){//Method implementation}
```

This has the added benefit of automatically providing a 'Try POSTing' button when someone does a get via the browswer.

This is the behavior seen in Jenkins when accessing the '/exit' url.